# Need to show that a set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Consider the set $$K=\left\{\binom x y\in \mathbb R^2\ :\ 0\leq x\leq 1\ \text{and} \ 0\leq y\leq \sqrt x \right\}.$$

If I want to show that $K$  is compact, so in fact I need to show it is closed and bounded.

For bounded, is it enough to say that for every $P \in K$, $d(P,0)\leq \sqrt 2$ ?

For closed,  I want to show that for every convergent $(P_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in K$ $\Rightarrow $ $\underset {n \rightarrow \infty } {\lim} P_n\in K$.

So is it enough to say that $P_n = \binom {x_n} {y_n} \rightarrow \binom {x_0} {y_0}$  with $P_n \in K$ for every $n$ we get $x_n \rightarrow x_0$  with $0\leq x_n \leq 1$ and so $x_0$ must also be between $0$ and $1$ (and same for $y_0$).

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry. Is it enough to show that $k$ is bounded and closed?

Comment: Yes, it is enough. But you did not prove that it is closed.

Comment: just note that since $0\leq y_n\leq \sqrt{x_n}$ for all $n$ then you have to have $0\leq y_0\leq\sqrt{x_0}$ so $K$ is sequentially closed, and thus closed, since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a metric space

Answer (score 1):

$K \subseteq [0,1]^2$, as is easy to see. So boundedness is easy.

If $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, $\{(x,y)\mid y \le f(x)\}$ is closed in the plane. Your set is a special case for $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ and intersected with $[0,1] \times \Bbb R$, which is also closed...